# React -Refresh button that refreshes only part of my page

Tags: reactjs, refresh

So I'm building a web app that contains a static header at the top that is always there on every page. I'm currently trying to find a function/method that could refresh the page I'm on without re-rendering the header.

Basically, I want to click the "Home" button and it refreshes the page Home but only the bottom part not the header. I've tried location.reload but it refreshes my entire page. Is there a way to only refresh the bottom part of my page?

The button that would refresh is in my header*

Here's my code for the main that renders my Header dumbed down:

Main.js

```
render(){
    return(

    <div className ="TextFont">
        <Header {...this.props}/>
            <div className="MarginTop">
                <Grid>
                    <LastVisit />
                    <Row className="show-grid MarginTop">
                        <ButtonGroup vertical >
                            <NewRequest  {...this.props}/>
                            <RequestInProgress  {...this.props}/>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Row className="show-grid">
                                        <Col sm={6} md={12}>{this.props.actions[0].showRequest &&  <RequestGrid {...this.props}/>    }</Col>
                                    </Row>
                                </Grid>                                 
                        </ButtonGroup>
                    </Row>
                </Grid>                       
            </div>
    </div>
    )
    }
   }
};
```

In Header, I want to call a method using a button to re-render the bottom part (so after < Header...>.

Thank you

Comment: what data you want to refresh? `location.reload` reloads page, it means entire React app will be reinitialized

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to avoid that. My goal here would be to refresh everything under the header. So in my main.js above, it would be from the _< div className="MarginTop">_ to the end of that div

Comment: Since I've posted this, I'm thinking about maybe putting all that **div** into another class and then rendering that class in my main (just like the Header above). Would that be easier then to re render that class without touching the header?

Comment: To re-render `Grid` you want to pass new props to it, Since you are passing all existing props to each component, you need to implement `shouldComponentUpdate` in `Header` and decide should it be updated or not according to new props, or narrow list of props for each component, so they would use only what needed

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense I didn't think of ShouldComponentUpdate. I'll check it out. Thanks